# Assign all custom fields to variables with the same name?

Tags: php, wordpress

If you have custom fields in a Wordpress post, is there a way to set all the custom fields to variables of that same name automatically?

I.e instead of

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
if (isset($custom_fields['field_1'][0])) { $field_1 = $custom_fields['field_1'][0]; }
if (isset($custom_fields['field_2'][0])) { $field_2 = $custom_fields['field_2'][0]; }
 etc.....
```

Is there a way to skip those ifs and simply assign every valid custom field to a var automatically?

Comment: It's doable, but not much help. You'll then have to check `if(isset($field_1))` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
foreach($custom_fields as $k => $v) {
  ${$k} = $v[0];
}
```

It works using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), setting the new variable as the key value, and its value is the 0-th index in the array, as you show in your question.